# How to get first record out of each group from the result retrieved by using group by command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Suppose if my Input is:

```
ID  GroupID  Qty
1         1  100
2         1  200
3         1  300
4         2  98
5         2  198
6         3  175
7         3  275
8         3  375
9         4  215
```

Output should be

```
ID   GroupID    Qty
 1         1    100
 4         2    98
 6         3    175
 9         4    215
```

Can any one help me how to do it with SQL Server `T-SQL` query?

Comment: could you be more clear? Inputs to what? Why should the output be that way? Are you inputting to a table? Maybe it's just the formatting that isn't clear.

Comment: Define "First". First as ordered by what? Is `Qty` always ascending within a group by `id` as per your sample data?

Comment: High quality question! You may have mentioned the SQL Server version you're using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
declare @T table (ID int, GroupID int, Qty int)
insert into @T values
(1, 1, 100),
(2, 1, 200),
(3, 1, 300),
(4, 2, 98),
(5, 2, 198),
(6, 3, 175),
(7, 3, 275),
(8, 3, 375),
(9, 4, 215)

;with cte as
(
  select
    ID,
    GroupID,
    Qty,
    rank() over(partition by GroupID order by ID) as rn
  from @T
)  
select ID, GroupID, Qty
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Perfect! However, I had to change the rank() to ROW_NUMBER() in my case. Thanks btw.

Comment: Great answer. [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) works in MSSQL 2005 and up. Not in MSSQL 2000.

Comment: `rank()` allows there to be ties and assigns tied rows the same number, e.g., `[1, 4, 4, 5]` gets ranks `[1, 2, 2, 4]`. `row_number()` assigns sequential numbers without ties and would return `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Answer (score 7):

EDIT

```
SELECT 
    MIN(ID) ,
    GroupID,
    (SELECT TOP 1 Qty FROM @TABLE T2 WHERE T2.ID = MIN(T1.ID))
FROM 
    @TABLE T1
GROUP BY
    GroupID
```

Input

```
 ID GroupID   Qty
    1   1   100
    2   1   200
    3   1   300
    4   2   98
    5   2   198
    6   3   175
    7   3   275
    8   3   375
    9   4   215
```

Output

```
1   1   100
4   2   98
6   3   175
9   4   215
```

Answer (score 3):

The best and more flexible way in my opinion would be to use ROW_NUMBER().
The below I've tested for your example, just replace **tmpTable** with your table name:

```
SELECT a.* FROM tmpTable a INNER JOIN 
(SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY ID, GroupID) AS SEQ, tmpTable.*
FROM            tmpTable) b
ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.GroupID = b.GroupID
WHERE b.SEQ = 1
```

read more about how to use ROW_NUMBER: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql

Comment: If the data you are ordering by in your partition has multiples of the same value (100,100,100,200,300), using `rank()` will return duplicate entries as each repeating value gets the same rank. I agree the `row_number()` approach might be more flexible in selecting the first value. I can't speak to performance impact on `row_number()` vs `rank()` though.

Comment: @gbeaven, for simplicity I didn't add another layer. To improve performance I would select records with SEQ = 1 and then join to the main table. Result of this would be a joint query with a smaller subset of records (to improve performance WHERE b.SEQ = 1 should be within subquery by adding another nested layer).