# Get top 1 row of each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table which I want to get the latest entry for each group. Here's the table:

`DocumentStatusLogs` Table

| ID | DocumentID | Status | DateCreated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | S1 | 7/29/2011 |
| 3 | 1 | S2 | 7/30/2011 |
| 6 | 1 | S1 | 8/02/2011 |
| 1 | 2 | S1 | 7/28/2011 |
| 4 | 2 | S2 | 7/30/2011 |
| 5 | 2 | S3 | 8/01/2011 |
| 6 | 3 | S1 | 8/02/2011 |

The table will be grouped by `DocumentID` and sorted by `DateCreated` in descending order. For each `DocumentID`, I want to get the latest status.

My preferred output:

| DocumentID | Status | DateCreated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S1 | 8/02/2011 |
| 2 | S3 | 8/01/2011 |
| 3 | S1 | 8/02/2011 |

- Is there any aggregate function to get only the top from each group? See pseudo-code `GetOnlyTheTop` below:

  ```
    SELECT
      DocumentID,
      GetOnlyTheTop(Status),
      GetOnlyTheTop(DateCreated)
    FROM DocumentStatusLogs
    GROUP BY DocumentID
    ORDER BY DateCreated DESC
  ```
- If such function doesn't exist, is there any way I can achieve the output I want?
- Or at the first place, could this be caused by unnormalized database? I'm thinking, since what I'm looking for is just one row, should that `status` also be located in the parent table?

Please see the parent table for more information:

Current `Documents` Table

| DocumentID | Title | Content | DateCreated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TitleA | ... | ... |
| 2 | TitleB | ... | ... |
| 3 | TitleC | ... | ... |

Should the parent table be like this so that I can easily access its status?

| DocumentID | Title | Content | DateCreated | CurrentStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TitleA | ... | ... | s1 |
| 2 | TitleB | ... | ... | s3 |
| 3 | TitleC | ... | ... | s1 |

**UPDATE**
I just learned how to use "apply" which makes it easier to address such problems.

Comment: For a more detailed discussion and comparison of possible solutions I recommend to read the similar question on dba.se: [Retrieving n rows per group](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/86415/57105).

Comment: I looked at the post and tried it. Using *group by StoreID* generated an error.

Comment: Related: [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: This question is for MS SQL Server, question [Select first row in each GROUP BY group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group) is for Postgres. The language constructs can be different.

Answer (score 969, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocumentID ORDER BY DateCreated DESC) AS rn
   FROM DocumentStatusLogs
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

If you expect 2 entries per day, then this will arbitrarily pick one. To get both entries for a day, use DENSE_RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER.

As for normalised or not, it depends if you want to:

- maintain status in 2 places
- preserve status history
- ...

As it stands, you preserve status history. If you want latest status in the parent table too (which is denormalisation) you'd need a trigger to maintain "status" in the parent. or drop this status history table.

Comment: And... What is `Partition By`? `With` is new to me also :( I'm using mssql 2005 anyway.

Comment: @domanokz: Partition By resets the count. So in this case, it says to count per DocumentID

Comment: Hm, I worry about the performance, I'll be querying millions of rows. Is SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...) affects the performance? Also, is `ROW_NUMBER` some kind of a subquery for each row?

Comment: @domanokz: no, it's not a subquery. If you have correct indexes then millions shouldn't be a problem. There are only 2 set based ways anyway: this and the aggregate (Ariel's solution). So try them both...

Comment: would you mind to look at my question again? I've edited it, I added the ID to DocumentStatusLogs table. I think it might help us to optimize the query. Thanks!

Comment: @domanokz: Just change ORDER BY DateCreated DESC to ORDER BY ID DESC

Comment: This is great, I'm used to subquery for this task. I find this solutions much more appealing.

Comment: this so simple and effective. Much more efficient than some subqueries. Thank you !

Comment: What is the starting semicolon for?

Comment: @Caltor I left the ; when having above in a larger SQL statement and got the following error: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.' A GO just before - or no other statement - works as well.

Comment: Used in my context, the CTE solution is much quicker than the CROSS APPLY: a couple of seconds in the first case (less than 10) vs 56 mins in the second one. That's appreciable!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in sql server?! I get the error 'invalid column name rn'

Answer (score 255):

I just learned how to use `cross apply`. Here's how to use it in this scenario:

```
 select d.DocumentID, ds.Status, ds.DateCreated 
 from Documents as d 
 cross apply 
     (select top 1 Status, DateCreated
      from DocumentStatusLogs 
      where DocumentID = d.DocumentId
      order by DateCreated desc) as ds
```

Comment: Doesn't this give you the date the document was created, not the date the status was created?

Comment: That actually makes no difference since the issue is still addressed.

Comment: I just posted the results of my timing tests against all of the proposed solutions and yours came out on top.  Giving you an up vote :-)

Comment: +1 for huge speed improvement. This is much faster than a windowing function such as ROW_NUMBER(). It would be nice if SQL recognized ROW_NUMBER() = 1 like queries and optimized them into Applies.  Note:  I used OUTER APPLY as I needed results, even if they didn't exist in the apply.

Comment: I didn't get improvement but idea is interesting

Comment: @TamusJRoyce  you can't extrapolate that just because it was faster once this is always the case. It depends. As described here http://sqlmag.com/database-development/optimizing-top-n-group-queries

Comment: My comment is about having multiple rows, and only desiring one of those multiple rows per group. Joins are for when you want one to many. Applies are for when you have one to many, but want to filter out all except a one to one. Scenario: For 100 members, give me each their best phone number (where each could have several numbers). This is where Apply excels. Less reads = less disk access = better performance. Given my experience is with poorly designed non-normalized databases.

Comment: @MartinSmith From your article, "Some solutions work well only when the right indexes are available, but without those indexes the solutions perform badly." - Great point! The above scenario is when you are able to view execution plan and add indexes where needed. If you are not able to add indexes, you will need to do a case-by-case test (which you should probably do anyways).

Comment: This has to be black magic. This helped me to find the most recent entry and the first entry for each resource returned. Very useful.

Comment: @dpp your answer is not giving me one row per group. It is returning the whole group? Am I missing something.

Comment: This works well when you already have a separate `Documents` table that gives one row per group, as desired in the output. But if you're only working with the one table (`DocumentStatusLogs` in this case), you'd first have to do some sort of `DISTINCT` operation on `DocumentID` (or `ROW_NUMBER()`, `MAX(ID)`, etc.), losing all that gained performance.

Comment: This works very well. But keep in mind that if you need to preserve the select results even if APPLY returns empty, then you need to use OUTER APPLY rather than CROSS APPLY.

Comment: I just heard about cross apply, the practical of it is kind of confusing. some people comparing this with ``inner join``, question is:
``inner join`` states the ``connectors`` or pk to fk. But ``Cross Apply`` doesn't. How do we grouping it with ``cross apply`` does it automatically detecting the same column name? 
this thread might me outdated but I really want to know. Thank you for the knowledge @dpp

Comment: @Extragorey, totally agree. I was having a query for most recent results for a device-command pairs from the 'results' table hanging intermittently - for indefinite time. And the main problem was a full scan of the 'results' table to obtain these pairs. So I just made a new table with device and command columns and unique primary key on both, and then applied dpp's solution. It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 242):

I know this is an old thread but the `TOP 1 WITH TIES` solutions is quite nice and might be helpful to some reading through the solutions.

```
select top 1 with ties
   DocumentID
  ,Status
  ,DateCreated
from DocumentStatusLogs
order by row_number() over (partition by DocumentID order by DateCreated desc)
```

The `select top 1 with ties` clause tells SQL Server that you want to return the first row per group. But how does SQL Server know how to group up the data? This is where the `order by row_number() over (partition by DocumentID order by DateCreated desc` comes in. The column/columns after `partition by` defines how SQL Server groups up the data. Within each group, the rows will be sorted based on the `order by` columns. Once sorted, the top row in each group will be returned in the query.

More about the TOP clause can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql).

Comment: agreed - this best replicates what is very easy to do in other versions of SQL and other languages imo

Comment: I agree that this is an elegant solution.  In my particular query and on SQL Server 2019  this was twice as slow as the cross apply with top 1 solution, but measure for yourself.

Comment: Hmm, 'With Ties' might cause more rows to be returned than the value specified in expression (TOP 1). If the OP wants only 1, then you need to remove this phrase, right?

Comment: @TKBruin that is why the order by row_number() is required. This allows the top record per partition to be retrieved.

Comment: This deserves to be the best answer... its speed is absolutely compareable to using CTE with window function, but its so much more maintainable... I have hundrets of satellite tables in my DataVault models and with this solution I don't have to retype the attribute projection again and again for each table to get a view on its most recent entry. Also this solution is often faster than joining to the PIT Table to get the latest entries. Truly a gamechanger for me

Comment: Does CROSS APPLY have any use here instead?

Answer (score 62):

I've done some timings over the various recommendations here, and the results really depend on the size of the table involved, but the most consistent solution is using the CROSS APPLY  These tests were run against SQL Server 2008-R2, using a table with 6,500 records, and another (identical schema) with 137 million records.  The columns being queried are part of the primary key on the table, and the table width is very small (about 30 bytes).  The times are reported by SQL Server from the actual execution plan.

```
Query                                  Time for 6500 (ms)    Time for 137M(ms)

CROSS APPLY                                    17.9                17.9
SELECT WHERE col = (SELECT MAX(COL)…)           6.6               854.4
DENSE_RANK() OVER PARTITION                     6.6               907.1
```

I think the really amazing thing was how consistent the time was for the CROSS APPLY regardless of the number of rows involved.

Comment: It all depends on the data distribution and available indexes. It was discussed at great lengths on [dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group).

Answer (score 47):

If you're worried about performance, you can also do this with `MAX()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM DocumentStatusLogs D
WHERE DateCreated = (SELECT MAX(DateCreated) FROM DocumentStatusLogs WHERE ID = D.ID)
```

`ROW_NUMBER()` requires a sort of all the rows in your `SELECT` statement, whereas `MAX` does not. Should drastically speed up your query.

Comment: Cannot performance issues with ROW_NUMBER() be addressed with proper indexing? (I feel that should be done anyhow)

Comment: With datetime, you cannot guarantee two entries won't be added on the same date and time. Precision isn't high enough.

Comment: +1 for simplicity. @TamusJRoyce is right. What about? 'select * from DocumentStatusLog D where ID = (select ID from DocumentsStatusLog where D.DocumentID = DocumentID order by DateCreated DESC limit 1);'

Comment: SELECT *
FROM EventScheduleTbl D
WHERE DatesPicked = (SELECT top 1 min(DatesPicked)
      FROM EventScheduleTbl 
       WHERE EventIDf = D.EventIDf and DatesPicked>= convert(date,getdate()) )

Comment: There are definitely cases where this will outperform `row_number()` even with proper indexing. I find it especially valuable in self-join scenarios. The thing to be cognizant of  though, is that this method will often yield a higher number of both logical reads and scan counts, despite reporting a low subtree cost. You'll need to weigh the cost/benefits in your particular case to determine if it's actually better.

Comment: In my case, this approach was SLOWER than using ROW_NUMBER(), due to the introduction of a subquery.  You should test different approaches to see what performs best for your data.

Comment: I up-voted this answer for its compliance with the SQL standard: this approach also works in databases that are not SQL Server.

Answer (score 35):

This is one of the most easily found question on the topic, so I wanted to give a modern answer to the it (both for my reference and to help others out). By using `first_value` and `over` you can make short work of the above query:

```
Select distinct DocumentID
  , first_value(status) over (partition by DocumentID order by DateCreated Desc) as Status
  , first_value(DateCreated) over (partition by DocumentID order by DateCreated Desc) as DateCreated
From DocumentStatusLogs
```

This should work in SQL Server 2012 and up. `First_value` can be thought of as a way to accomplish `Select Top 1` when using an `over` clause. `Over` allows grouping in the select list so instead of writing nested subqueries (like many of the existing answers do), this does it in a more readable fashion.

Comment: This doesn't work in SQL Server 2008 R2. I think first_value was introduced in 2012!

Comment: Very fast! I was using the Cross Apply solution offered by @dpp, but this one is waaaay faster.

Comment: For large numbers of columns (Status, DateCreated, etc.), does this do a separate partition/sort for each column, or does it get optimised into one?

Answer (score 30):

```
SELECT * FROM
DocumentStatusLogs JOIN (
  SELECT DocumentID, MAX(DateCreated) DateCreated
  FROM DocumentStatusLogs
  GROUP BY DocumentID
  ) max_date USING (DocumentID, DateCreated)
```

What database server? This code doesn't work on all of them.

Regarding the second half of your question, it seems reasonable to me to include the status as a column. You can leave `DocumentStatusLogs` as a log, but still store the latest info in the main table.

BTW, if you already have the `DateCreated` column in the Documents table you can just join `DocumentStatusLogs` using that (as long as `DateCreated` is unique in `DocumentStatusLogs`).

Edit: MsSQL does not support USING, so change it to:

```
ON DocumentStatusLogs.DocumentID = max_date.DocumentID AND DocumentStatusLogs.DateCreated = max_date.DateCreated
```

Comment: The clue was in the title: MSSQL. SQL Server does not have USING but the idea is OK.

Comment: @gbn The stupid moderators usually delete important keywords from titles, as they have done here. Making it very difficult to find the correct answers in search results or Google.

Comment: Jus to point out that this "solution" can still give you multiple records if you have a tie on the `max(DateCreated)`

Comment: Remove the Using (in MS SQL ) and complete the Join code , then it would work .

Answer (score 17):

Here are 3 separate approaches to the problem in hand along with the best choices of indexing for each of those queries (please try out the indexes yourselves and see the logical read, elapsed time, execution plan. I have provided the suggestions from my experience on such queries without executing for this specific problem).

**Approach 1**: Using ROW_NUMBER(). If rowstore index is not being able to enhance the performance, you can try out nonclustered/clustered columnstore index as for queries with aggregation and grouping and for tables which are ordered by in different columns all the times, columnstore index usually is the best choice.

```
;WITH CTE AS
    (
       SELECT   *,
                RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocumentID ORDER BY DateCreated DESC)
       FROM     DocumentStatusLogs
    )
    SELECT  ID      
        ,DocumentID 
        ,Status     
        ,DateCreated
    FROM    CTE
    WHERE   RN = 1;
```

**Approach 2**: Using FIRST_VALUE. If rowstore index is not being able to enhance the performance, you can try out nonclustered/clustered columnstore index as for queries with aggregation and grouping and for tables which are ordered by in different columns all the times, columnstore index usually is the best choice.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
    ID      = FIRST_VALUE(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY DocumentID ORDER BY DateCreated DESC)
    ,DocumentID
    ,Status     = FIRST_VALUE(Status) OVER (PARTITION BY DocumentID ORDER BY DateCreated DESC)
    ,DateCreated    = FIRST_VALUE(DateCreated) OVER (PARTITION BY DocumentID ORDER BY DateCreated DESC)
FROM    DocumentStatusLogs;
```

**Approach 3**: Using CROSS APPLY. Creating rowstore index on DocumentStatusLogs table covering the columns used in the query should be enough to cover the query without need of a columnstore index.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
    ID      = CA.ID
    ,DocumentID = D.DocumentID
    ,Status     = CA.Status 
    ,DateCreated    = CA.DateCreated
FROM    DocumentStatusLogs D
    CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT  TOP 1 I.*
            FROM    DocumentStatusLogs I
            WHERE   I.DocumentID = D.DocumentID
            ORDER   BY I.DateCreated DESC
            ) CA;
```

Comment: I have a 100M rows table where I nedded to get both the 1st and the last record for each group. The first two approaches took several minutes to execute. Approach 3 took less than a second.

Answer (score 11):

This is quite an old thread, but I thought I'd throw my two cents in just the same as the accepted answer didn't work particularly well for me.  I tried gbn's solution on a large dataset and found it to be terribly slow (>45 seconds on 5 million plus records in SQL Server 2012).  Looking at the execution plan it's obvious that the issue is that it requires a SORT operation which slows things down significantly.

Here's an alternative that I lifted from the entity framework that needs no SORT operation and does a NON-Clustered Index search.  This reduces the execution time down to < 2 seconds on the aforementioned record set.

```
SELECT 
[Limit1].[DocumentID] AS [DocumentID], 
[Limit1].[Status] AS [Status], 
[Limit1].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated]
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT [Extent1].[DocumentID] AS [DocumentID] FROM [dbo].[DocumentStatusLogs] AS [Extent1]) AS [Distinct1]
OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Project2].[ID] AS [ID], [Project2].[DocumentID] AS [DocumentID], [Project2].[Status] AS [Status], [Project2].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated]
    FROM (SELECT 
        [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID], 
        [Extent2].[DocumentID] AS [DocumentID], 
        [Extent2].[Status] AS [Status], 
        [Extent2].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated]
        FROM [dbo].[DocumentStatusLogs] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Distinct1].[DocumentID] = [Extent2].[DocumentID])
    )  AS [Project2]
    ORDER BY [Project2].[ID] DESC) AS [Limit1]
```

Now I'm assuming something that isn't entirely specified in the original question, but if your table design is such that your ID column is an auto-increment ID, and the DateCreated is set to the current date with each insert, then even without running with my query above you could actually get a sizable performance boost to gbn's solution (about half the execution time) just from **ordering on ID instead of ordering on DateCreated** as this will provide an identical sort order and it's a faster sort.

Comment: This can be simplified: The code inside the outer apply does not have to have two leveles of select.

Answer (score 5):

My code to select top 1 from each group

```
select a.* from #DocumentStatusLogs a where 
 datecreated in( select top 1 datecreated from #DocumentStatusLogs b
where 
a.documentid = b.documentid
order by datecreated desc
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Verifying Clint's awesome and correct answer from above:

The performance between the two queries below is interesting. 52% being the top one. And 48% being the second one. A 4% improvement in performance using DISTINCT instead of ORDER BY. But ORDER BY has the advantage to sort by multiple columns.

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DocumentStatusLogs') IS NOT NULL) BEGIN DROP TABLE #DocumentStatusLogs END

CREATE TABLE #DocumentStatusLogs (
    [ID] int NOT NULL,
    [DocumentID] int NOT NULL,
    [Status] varchar(20),
    [DateCreated] datetime
)

INSERT INTO #DocumentStatusLogs([ID], [DocumentID], [Status], [DateCreated]) VALUES (2, 1, 'S1', '7/29/2011 1:00:00')
INSERT INTO #DocumentStatusLogs([ID], [DocumentID], [Status], [DateCreated]) VALUES (3, 1, 'S2', '7/30/2011 2:00:00')
INSERT INTO #DocumentStatusLogs([ID], [DocumentID], [Status], [DateCreated]) VALUES (6, 1, 'S1', '8/02/2011 3:00:00')
INSERT INTO #DocumentStatusLogs([ID], [DocumentID], [Status], [DateCreated]) VALUES (1, 2, 'S1', '7/28/2011 4:00:00')
INSERT INTO #DocumentStatusLogs([ID], [DocumentID], [Status], [DateCreated]) VALUES (4, 2, 'S2', '7/30/2011 5:00:00')
INSERT INTO #DocumentStatusLogs([ID], [DocumentID], [Status], [DateCreated]) VALUES (5, 2, 'S3', '8/01/2011 6:00:00')
INSERT INTO #DocumentStatusLogs([ID], [DocumentID], [Status], [DateCreated]) VALUES (6, 3, 'S1', '8/02/2011 7:00:00')
```

Option 1:

```
    SELECT
    [Extent1].[ID], 
    [Extent1].[DocumentID],
    [Extent1].[Status], 
    [Extent1].[DateCreated]
FROM #DocumentStatusLogs AS [Extent1]
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1
            [Extent2].[ID], 
            [Extent2].[DocumentID],
            [Extent2].[Status], 
            [Extent2].[DateCreated]
        FROM #DocumentStatusLogs AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent1].[DocumentID] = [Extent2].[DocumentID]
        ORDER BY [Extent2].[DateCreated] DESC, [Extent2].[ID] DESC
    ) AS [Project2]
WHERE ([Project2].[ID] IS NULL OR [Project2].[ID] = [Extent1].[ID])
```

Option 2:

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[DocumentID] AS [ID], 
    [Limit1].[DocumentID] AS [DocumentID], 
    [Limit1].[Status] AS [Status], 
    [Limit1].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Extent1].[DocumentID] AS [DocumentID] FROM #DocumentStatusLogs AS [Extent1]
) AS [Distinct1]
    OUTER APPLY  (
        SELECT TOP (1) [Project2].[ID] AS [ID], [Project2].[DocumentID] AS [DocumentID], [Project2].[Status] AS [Status], [Project2].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated]
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID], 
                [Extent2].[DocumentID] AS [DocumentID], 
                [Extent2].[Status] AS [Status], 
                [Extent2].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated]
            FROM #DocumentStatusLogs AS [Extent2]
            WHERE [Distinct1].[DocumentID] = [Extent2].[DocumentID]
        )  AS [Project2]
        ORDER BY [Project2].[ID] DESC
    ) AS [Limit1]
```

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio: after highlighting and running the first block, highlight both Option 1 and Option 2, right click -> [Display Estimated Execution Plan]. Then run the entire thing to see the results.

Option 1 Results:

```
ID  DocumentID  Status  DateCreated
6   1   S1  8/2/11 3:00
5   2   S3  8/1/11 6:00
6   3   S1  8/2/11 7:00
```

Option 2 Results:

```
ID  DocumentID  Status  DateCreated
6   1   S1  8/2/11 3:00
5   2   S3  8/1/11 6:00
6   3   S1  8/2/11 7:00
```

Note:

> I tend to use APPLY when I want a join to be 1-to-(1 of many).
>
> I use a JOIN if I want the join to be 1-to-many, or many-to-many.
>
> I avoid CTE with ROW_NUMBER() unless I need to do something advanced and am ok with the windowing performance penalty.

I also avoid EXISTS / IN subqueries in the WHERE or ON clause, as I have experienced this causing some terrible execution plans. But mileage varies. Review the execution plan and profile performance where and when needed!

Answer (score 5):

This solution can be used to get the TOP N most recent rows for each partition (in the example, N is 1 in the WHERE statement and partition is doc_id):

```
SELECT T.doc_id, T.status, T.date_created FROM 
(
    SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY doc_id ORDER BY date_created DESC) AS rnk FROM doc a
) T
WHERE T.rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

`CROSS APPLY` was the method I used for my solution, as it worked for me, and for my clients needs. And from what I've read, should provide the best overall performance should their database grow substantially.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT o.*
FROM `DocumentStatusLogs` o                   
  LEFT JOIN `DocumentStatusLogs` b                   
  ON o.DocumentID = b.DocumentID AND o.DateCreated < b.DateCreated
 WHERE b.DocumentID is NULL ;
```

If you want to return only recent document order by DateCreated, it will return only top 1 document by DocumentID

Comment: This is just going to return everything in the table.

Answer (score 0):

In scenarios where you want to avoid using row_count(), you can also use a left join:

```
select ds.DocumentID, ds.Status, ds.DateCreated 
from DocumentStatusLogs ds
left join DocumentStatusLogs filter 
    ON ds.DocumentID = filter.DocumentID
    -- Match any row that has another row that was created after it.
    AND ds.DateCreated < filter.DateCreated
-- then filter out any rows that matched 
where filter.DocumentID is null
```

For the example schema, you could also use a "not in subquery", which generally compiles to the same output as the left join:

```
select ds.DocumentID, ds.Status, ds.DateCreated 
from DocumentStatusLogs ds
WHERE ds.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT filter.ID 
    FROM DocumentStatusLogs filter
    WHERE ds.DocumentID = filter.DocumentID
        AND ds.DateCreated < filter.DateCreated)
```

Note, the subquery pattern wouldn't work if the table didn't have at least one single-column unique key/constraint/index, in this case the primary key "Id".

Both of these queries tend to be more "expensive" than the row_count() query (as measured by Query Analyzer).  However, you might encounter scenarios where they return results faster or enable other optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Some database engines* are starting to support the `QUALIFY` clause that allows to filter the result of window functions (which the accepted answer uses).

So the accepted answer can become

```sql
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocumentID ORDER BY DateCreated DESC) AS rn
FROM DocumentStatusLogs
QUALIFY rn = 1
```

See this article for an in depth explanation: https://jrandrews.net/the-joy-of-qualify

You can use this tool to see  which database support this clause: https://www.jooq.org/translate/
There is an option to transform the qualify clause when the target dialect does not support it.

*Teradata, BigQuery, H2, Snowflake...

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT [DocumentID]
    ,[tmpRez].value('/x[2]', 'varchar(20)') AS [Status]
    ,[tmpRez].value('/x[3]', 'datetime') AS [DateCreated]
FROM (
    SELECT [DocumentID]
        ,cast('<x>' + max(cast([ID] AS VARCHAR(10)) + '</x><x>' + [Status] + '</x><x>' + cast([DateCreated] AS VARCHAR(20))) + '</x>' AS XML) AS [tmpRez]
    FROM DocumentStatusLogs
    GROUP BY DocumentID
    ) AS [tmpQry]
```

Comment: You should always describe your SQL statement how it will work and solve the OP's query.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT documentid, 
       status, 
       datecreated 
FROM   documentstatuslogs dlogs 
WHERE  status = (SELECT status 
                 FROM   documentstatuslogs 
                 WHERE  documentid = dlogs.documentid 
                 ORDER  BY datecreated DESC 
                 LIMIT  1)
```

Comment: That's MySQL syntax not SQL server

Answer (score -1):

I believe this can be done just like this. This might need some tweaking but you can just select the max from the group.

These answers are overkill..

```
SELECT
  d.DocumentID,
  MAX(d.Status),
  MAX(d1.DateCreated)
FROM DocumentStatusLogs d, DocumentStatusLogs d1
USING DocumentID
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Comment: Is this t-sql? `Using` isn't supported like that...

Comment: mysql 8 should support @PedroC88

Comment: Yeah I mention it because the OP specified sql-server

Comment: @PedroC88 the question seems to have been changed so that it doesn't reference sql-server anymore. so this is an OK answer.

Comment: It’s on the tags

Comment: @PedroC88 If you look at the other comments, it was originally a question specific to that platform but the question changed. Downvoting in this case misses the mark.

Comment: Syntax error. And will not return the _row_ having the latest timestamp (for each id.)

Comment: @Unionfind, I know this is a bit of a necro-comment, but the question is still quite specific to SQL Server. Check the tags: [[sql]] [[sql-server]] [[t-sql]] [[sql-server-2005]] [[greatest-n-per-group]]. (On SO, tags are not some sort of decorative bling: they're an integral part of the question definition.)

Comment: @Martha I think that can be debated. The site isn't quite that consistent. Tag limits also render that somewhat aspirational.