# After using SELECT DISTINCT with inner join, still getting duplicate record

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am using inner join in three tables. I want to get only unique record, not duplicates. So I used `SELECT DISTINCT` with inner join. But still getting duplicates record.

**My code**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Submission.MID AS Expr16,
    RevAssaignments.Rev1Name AS Expr18, 
    RevAssaignments.Rev2Name AS Expr19, 
    RevAssaignments.Rev3Name AS Expr20, 
    RevAssaignments.Rev1Status AS Expr21, 
    RevAssaignments.Rev2Status AS Expr22, 
    RevAssaignments.Rev3Status AS Expr23, 
    Submission.Title AS Expr2, 
    Submission.SID AS Expr1, 
    Files.PaperKey AS Expr7, 
    Submission.CoAuth AS Expr3, 
    Submission.Email AS Expr4, 
    Submission.CopyRightDate AS Expr5, 
    Submission.Status AS Expr6, 
    Files.* 
FROM RevAssaignments
    INNER JOIN Submission ON RevAssaignments.SID = Submission.SID
    INNER JOIN Files ON Submission.SID = Files.SID
WHERE (Submission.Status = 'ACCEPTED  ')
ORDER BY Expr16
```

**Output**

```
I-2012-10-355   Modified Sierpinski Carpet Fractal Antenna for Wireless Applications    354 2701318277.pdf  Kuldip Pahwa

I-2012-10-355   Modified Sierpinski Carpet Fractal Antenna for Wireless Applications    354 1488315706.pdf  Kuldip Pahwa

I-2012-10-355   Modified Sierpinski Carpet Fractal Antenna for Wireless Applications    354 3539969905.pdf  Kuldip Pahwa

I-2012-12-379   Modified Dither Optical Phase Locked Loop for Inter-satellite Communications    378 1978719613.pdf  A.BANERJEE

I-2012-12-379   Modified Dither Optical Phase Locked Loop for Inter-satellite Communications    378 1063820967.pdf  A.BANERJEE

I-2012-12-379   Modified Dither Optical Phase Locked Loop for Inter-satellite Communications    378 9443420594.pdf  A.BANERJEE

I-2012-12-385   A Sampling Oscilloscope Based System with Active RF/IF Load-pull for Multi-Tone Non-linear Device Characterization  384 1383013331.pdf  Dr. Muhammad Akmal Chaudhary

I-2013-4-435    DESIGN OF MICROSTRIP YAGI UDA ANTENNA WITH THREE PARASITIC ELEMENTS AT 2.5 GHz  434 2012614214.pdf  satyandra singh lodhi

I-2013-4-435    DESIGN OF MICROSTRIP YAGI UDA ANTENNA WITH THREE PARASITIC ELEMENTS AT 2.5 GHz  434 1349118729.pdf  satyandra singh lodhi
```

**Desired Output**

```
I-2012-10-355   Modified Sierpinski Carpet Fractal Antenna for Wireless Applications    354 3539969905.pdf  Kuldip Pahwa

I-2012-12-379   Modified Dither Optical Phase Locked Loop for Inter-satellite Communications    378 9443420594.pdf  A.BANERJEE

I-2012-12-385   A Sampling Oscilloscope Based System with Active RF/IF Load-pull for Multi-Tone Non-linear Device Characterization  384 1383013331.pdf  Dr. Muhammad Akmal Chaudhary

I-2013-4-435    DESIGN OF MICROSTRIP YAGI UDA ANTENNA WITH THREE PARASITIC ELEMENTS AT 2.5 GHz  434 1349118729.pdf  satyandra singh lodhi
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get first record out of each group from the result retrieved by using group by command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225113/how-to-get-first-record-out-of-each-group-from-the-result-retrieved-by-using-gro)

Answer (score 1):

as you may noticed, fileNames are different (2701318277.pdf, 1488315706.pdf, 9443420594.pdf), distinct command unified all records that share same values for all fields)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have multiple results for your join in your Files table. You could reach your desired output if you perform the join only on 1 row in Files table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Submission.MID AS Expr16
      , RevAssaignments.Rev1Name AS Expr18
      , RevAssaignments.Rev2Name AS Expr19
      , RevAssaignments.Rev3Name AS Expr20
      , RevAssaignments.Rev1Status AS Expr21
      , RevAssaignments.Rev2Status AS Expr22
      , RevAssaignments.Rev3Status AS Expr23
      , Submission.Title AS Expr2
      , Submission.SID AS Expr1
      , Files.PaperKey AS Expr7
      , Submission.CoAuth AS Expr3
      , Submission.Email AS Expr4
      , Submission.CopyRightDate AS Expr5
      , Submission.Status AS Expr6
      , Files.* 
      FROM RevAssaignments 
      INNER JOIN Submission ON RevAssaignments.SID = Submission.SID 
      INNER JOIN Files ON Files.SID = ( SELECT Files.FID FROM Files WHERE Files.SID = Submission SID (ORDER BY if needed) LIMIT 1)
      WHERE (Submission.Status = 'ACCEPTED ') ORDER BY Expr16
```

Comment: Thank you so much. still I am getting an error when I am executing above query. Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: You could use `SELECT TOP 1 Files.FID...` instead of the `LIMIT 1` at the end.