# SQL query which contains the order in which employees joined against each manager

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

[image]

[image]

I want to write a query against this table, such that it will return the list of employees in an order of date of joining as per the sequence of `Manager_ID`.

It should be able to tell the reportee that joined most recently for each manager.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get first record out of each group from the result retrieved by using group by command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225113/how-to-get-first-record-out-of-each-group-from-the-result-retrieved-by-using-gro)

Comment: Please post the data in text format. Also, please show what you have already tried.

Comment: You need to learn how to use `ORDER BY`. Please make the basic effort of googling it and trying something.

Comment: my table description is in the keyword, enter image description here. you can get from there

Comment: please show input and expected output in text format. By text format, I mean something we can copy paste. Not an image. Also, as others suggested, please try and show us what you have tried.

Comment: Pankaj.  You will get better answers by posting a complete example with the question.  Provide the CODE that will create a table (a #temp table is ok), populate with some data with INSERT statements, and then list the desired results...and show what you tried.  Arguing with people who might help you is not going to help your cause. (in regards to your comment about a screen shot).  You need to help your cause...by providing CODE, not screen shots that someone has to type from.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
<TABLE>
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT MANAGER_ID
     , MAX(DATE_OF_JOINING) AS MAX_DATE
FROM <TABLE>
GROUP BY MANAGER_ID     
) MAX_MANAGER
ON <TABLE>.MANAGER_ID = MAX_MANAGER.MANAGER_ID
AND <TABLE>.DATE_OF_JOINING = MAX_MANAGER.MAX_DATE
```

If two employees were hired the same day for the same manager you have two rows.