# Select unique rows from a select query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

[image]I have procedure in which I am getting data from 4 tables by joining them.

Here is my code

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetServiceRequestforLead]
    @professionalArea nvarchar (35) = '',
    @status nvarchar (15) = '',
    @experience nvarchar (15) = '',
    @PageNumber    BIGINT = 1, 
    @PageSize      BIGINT =20,
    @userid bigint = 0
AS 
BEGIN 
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY sc.Addeddate DESC) AS Row, sc.*
            , TotalRows = Count(*) OVER()
        FROM (
            select Mod_UserDetails.Email as LeadEmailId, Mod_UserDetails.ID as LeaduserId
                , ProfessionType, Mod_UserDetails.FirstName as LeadFirstName, Mod_UserDetails.LastName as LeadLastName
                , Mod_UserDetails.PhoneNo1 as LeadMobile
                , f.*
            from Lead_RequestForm f
            inner join Lead_ProfessionalArea on Lead_ProfessionalArea.ID = f.Profession
            left join ServiceProviderRequestMapping on f.RequestId =  ServiceProviderRequestMapping.RequestId    
            left join mod_userdetails on mod_userdetails.ID  = ServiceProviderRequestMapping.Leaduserid        
            where f.ExperienceRequired like  '%'+@experience+'%'
            AND f.Status like '%' + @status + '%'
            AND Lead_ProfessionalArea.ProfessionType like '%'+ @professionalArea +'%'
            AND (ServiceProviderRequestMapping.IsDeleted is null OR ServiceProviderRequestMapping.IsDeleted = 0)  
        )   sc 
    ) AS query  
    WHERE  row > (  @PageSize   *( @PageNumber -1))  
    AND row <= (  @PageSize   *   @PageNumber  )  
END
```

By executing this I am getting more than one row for `RequestId` column of  `Lead_RequestForm f` table. Data is unique in both the rows but reuqest id is the same. I want to get only the first record with the same Requestid column.

i  have added snap here request id column has duplicate value i want only one roq with a request id so want to select first one only

Comment: please provide sample input out put data

Comment: @sandeeprawat  i have added a sanp of result

Comment: here Request id column i have bordered it has duplicate values i want to select only the first one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get first record out of each group from the result retrieved by using group by command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5225113/2029983)

Comment: yes it does how to do it with my scenario

Comment: You would need an ordering column. When you say first record, it doesn’t mean anything unless there is another column ( Id, sk or date field) which represents order. Do you have such a field in your data?

Comment: @Somy its the First column RowID as you can see in the picture

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get first record out of each group from the result retrieved by using group by command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225113/how-to-get-first-record-out-of-each-group-from-the-result-retrieved-by-using-gro)

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below -

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetServiceRequestforLead]
@professionalArea nvarchar (35) = '',
@status nvarchar (15) = '',
@experience nvarchar (15) = '',
@PageNumber    BIGINT = 1, 
@PageSize      BIGINT =20,
@userid bigint = 0
AS 
 BEGIN 
Select Tb.*
from
(SELECT t.*, row_number() OVER (partition by RequestId order by Rowid) as seq_nbr
FROM (
    SELECT Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY sc.Addeddate DESC) AS Row, sc.*
        , TotalRows = Count(*) OVER()
    FROM (
        select Mod_UserDetails.Email as LeadEmailId, Mod_UserDetails.ID as LeaduserId
            , ProfessionType, Mod_UserDetails.FirstName as LeadFirstName, Mod_UserDetails.LastName as LeadLastName
            , Mod_UserDetails.PhoneNo1 as LeadMobile
            , f.*
        from Lead_RequestForm f
        inner join Lead_ProfessionalArea on Lead_ProfessionalArea.ID = f.Profession
        left join ServiceProviderRequestMapping on f.RequestId =  ServiceProviderRequestMapping.RequestId    
        left join mod_userdetails on mod_userdetails.ID  = ServiceProviderRequestMapping.Leaduserid        
        where f.ExperienceRequired like  '%'+@experience+'%'
        AND f.Status like '%' + @status + '%'
        AND Lead_ProfessionalArea.ProfessionType like '%'+ @professionalArea +'%'
        AND (ServiceProviderRequestMapping.IsDeleted is null OR ServiceProviderRequestMapping.IsDeleted = 0)  
    )   sc 
) AS query  
WHERE  row > (  @PageSize   *( @PageNumber -1))  
AND row <= (  @PageSize   *   @PageNumber  ) 
)t
)Tb
where Tb.seq_nbr = 1
END
```